# JFrame does not hide when setVisible(false)

Tags: java, jframe

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Frame extends JFrame{
    Frame() {
        JFrame j = new JFrame();
        j.setBounds(100, 200, 120, 120);
        j.setTitle("null");
        j.setVisible(true);
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

public class test001 {

    public static void main (String Args[]){
        Frame f = new Frame();
         System.out.print("Visible = True");

        f.setVisible(false);
        System.out.print("Visible = false");
    }
}
```

after the setVisible(false) command. The JFrame Window still show on my desktop.
How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating another `JFrame` within your constructor. Assuming what you want is your `Frame` class to be invisible, do this:

```
class Frame extends JFrame {

   Frame() {
      setBounds(100, 200, 120, 120);
      setTitle("null");
      setVisible(true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
}

public class test001 {

   public static void main(String Args[]) {
      Frame f = new Frame();
      System.out.print("Visible = True");

      f.setVisible(false);
      System.out.print("Visible = false");
   }
}
```

Comment: Much better to lose the unnecessary subclassing.

Comment: (And you're missing the `EventQueue.invokeLater` boilerplate in `main`.)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your main method uses different JFrame that your constructor. Your Frame constructor creates new JFrame instance (using new JFrame). When you call f.setVisible(false), it goes to your frame, but not to created JFrame.

Comment: Ahh.. I see. Now I know whats going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your "Frame" class instanciates a new JFrame. Calling setVisible on the Frame does not affect the JFrame which is being shown.

You can fix it by either just using a JFrame instance, or just subclassing. Don't do both.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the two different frames you are referring to (this is the problem answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450488/1326149), you should do all the graphics operations in the EVT thread (because your program even if it works great for you could be not portable to different platforms).

Comment: @Alex This is a side answer, but I started with this specific problem answer. Did you notice "the two different frames" and the link ? I would not be surprised if there is a platform on which it still does not work after correction of two frames problem because of wrong threads usage.

Comment: I think that topic starter will never know this, because 2 years left since he was seen here for last time.

Comment: @Alex yeah it is a rather old question (I did not notice it earlier)  but the answers are here forever (Internet never forgets). It looks I am earning the archeologist badge :) . I'll be more careful in the future.